# Pass class contructor as function in another class

Tags: typescript

I have two classes (let's say class1 and class2) and I would like to make class2 part of class1 and instantiate it.

What I would like to manage is to:
I just add a complete example

```
const class1 = new Class1();
const class2 = new class1.Class2();
```

Any ideas?

Edit:

@spender gave the solution

```
class Class2{
   foo: number = 0
    constructor(foo: number) {
      this.foo = foo;
     }
     bar(){
       return this.foo;
     }
};

class Class1 {
    static c2: any;
    
    get Class2() {
        return Class1.c2;
    }
}
Class1.c2 = Class2;
var c1 = new Class1();
var c2 = new c1.Class2(42);

console.log(c2.bar())
```

Comment: you are asking to create an object having properties as the sum of two different classes?

Comment: Basically, to make the constructor of Class2 a function of Class1.

Comment: I have to confess you that your expectation isn't really very clear. I mean why should you want a constructor that's using `this` or `self` on another scope to instantiate a different class. But I'm surely short sighted.

Comment: I updated my answer covering the scenario where you are redefining the constructor of a given class using a function from another class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You could, for instance, do it like this, using a [class expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/class) and a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) that fetches, in this case, a static property of `Class1`

```js
class Class1 {
  get Class2() {
    return Class1.c2.bind(null, 42);
  }
}
Class1.c2 = class {
  constructor(foo) {
    console.log(`inner class constructed with ${foo}`);
  }
};
var c1 = new Class1();
var c2 = new c1.Class2();
```

Comment: Thanks, works like charm! One last question.
Do you know a way to hide the constructor parameter(42) from outside the classes, give it from within the Class1, and keep using the new keyword to instantiate Class2?
`var c2 = new c1.Class2() // but give 42 inside Class1`?

Comment: @NikosIliakis Yes you can, by using [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) against the constructor to partially apply constructor parameters. I updated my answer to show how this might be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking to have an object as the result of 2 merged objects this could be a solution:

```
const class1 = new Class1();
const class2 = new Class2();

let fusion= {
    ...class1 ,
    ...class2 
};
```

So for example:

```
let a = {name : 'John'};
let b = {surname : 'Doe'};

let fusion = {...a,...b}; //will be {name: 'John', surname: 'Doe'}
```

That solution uses the spread operator:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

If you meant something else please correct me.

But on the other hand if you really wanted to instantiate Class2 using the constructor belonging to Class1, you could do something very very shady like this:

```
Class2.constructor = Class1.constructor;
let obj = new Class2();
```

But you are assigning a new constructor to Class2 using a function belonging to Class1 and the result will be very dirty unless you know in advance what you are doing. But that's exactly what you asked for.

I'd like to mention the fact that this way Class1 and Class2 don't need to know each other in advance and the dependency to each of them is made in the caller domain.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have that kind of initialization, but you can have a similar way through a function call

```
class Class2 {
   test() {
       console.log('testing class 2')
   }
}

class Class1 {
    newClass2() {
       return new Class2();
    }

    test() {
       console.log('testing class 1')
   }
}

const class1 = new Class1();
class1.test() //testing class 1
const class2 = class1.newClass2(); //new class 2
class2.test() //testing class 2
```